# different aggregated sums of the same column based on categorical values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I have a dataframe accounting different LEGO pieces contained in each of my LEGO set boxes.
For each set box, there are always many different regular pieces, but somemtimes the box contains also some additional spare pieces.
So the dataframe has a boolean column to distinguish that condition.

Now I want to summarize the dataset so I get just one row per LEGO set (groupby set_id) with a new column for the total amount of pieces in that set box (aggregated sum of "quantity").

My problem is that I also want two additional columns for accounting how many of those pieces are "regular" and how many are "spare", based on the True/False column.

Is there any way of **calculating those three sum columns by creating just one additional dataframe and just one .agg() call**?

Instead of creating 3 dataframes and merging columns, which is my current approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
random.seed(1)

# creating sample data:
nrows=15
df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=["set_id","part_id","quantity","is_spare"])
df["set_id"]=["ABC"[random.randint(0,2)] for r in range(0,nrows)]
df["part_id"] = [random.randint(1000,8000) for n in range(0,nrows)]
df["quantity"] = [random.randint(1,10) for n in range(0,nrows)]
df["is_spare"]=[random.random()>0.75 for r in range(0,nrows)]
print(df)

# grouping into a new dfsummary dataframe: HOW TO DO IT IN JUST ONE STEP ?

# aggregate sum of ALL pieces:
dfsummary = df.groupby("set_id", as_index=False) \
  .agg(num_pieces=("quantity","sum"))

# aggregate sum of "normal" pieces:
dfsummary2 = df.loc[df["is_spare"]==False].groupby("set_id", as_index=False) \
  .agg(normal_pieces=("quantity","sum"))

# aggregate sum of "spare" pieces:
dfsummary3 = df.loc[df["is_spare"]==True].groupby("set_id", as_index=False) \
  .agg(spare_pieces=("quantity","sum"))

# Putting all aggregate columns together:
dfsummary = dfsummary \
  .merge(dfsummary2,on="set_id",how="left") \
  .merge(dfsummary3,on="set_id",how="left")

print(dfsummary)
```

##### ORIGINAL DATA:

```
   set_id  part_id  quantity  is_spare
0       A     4545         1     False
1       C     5976         1     False
2       A     7244         9     False
3       B     7284         1     False
4       A     1017         7     False
5       B     6700         4      True
6       B     4648         7     False
7       B     3181         1     False
8       C     6910         9     False
9       B     7568         4      True
10      A     2874         8      True
11      A     5842         8     False
12      B     1837         9     False
13      A     3600         4     False
14      B     1250         6     False
```

##### SUMMARIZED DATA:

```
  set_id  num_pieces  normal_pieces  spare_pieces
0      A          37             29           8.0
1      B          32             24           8.0
2      C          10             10           NaN
```

I saw this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66449429/how-to-efficiently-aggregate-the-same-column-using-different-aggregate-functions), but my case is somehow different because the sum() functions would only be applied to some rows of the target column depending on other column's True/False values.

##### EDIT:

I extend the original dataset with one more column (`color`) to check if @sammywemmy's answer could be scaled for grouping and unstacking several columns at a time:

```
df["color"]=[["black","grey","white","red"][random.randint(0,3)] \
 for r in range(0,nrows)]



   set_id  part_id  quantity  is_spare  color
0       A     4545         1     False    red
1       C     5976         1     False   grey
2       A     7244         9     False  white
3       B     7284         1     False  white
4       A     1017         7     False    red
5       B     6700         4      True    red
6       B     4648         7     False  black
7       B     3181         1     False    red
8       C     6910         9     False   grey
9       B     7568         4      True    red
10      A     2874         8      True    red
11      A     5842         8     False   grey
12      B     1837         9     False  white
13      A     3600         4     False  white
14      B     1250         6     False  black
```

##### SUMMARIZED DATA:

```
 set_id  num_pieces  normal_pieces  spare_pieces  black  grey   red  white
0      A          37             29           8.0    NaN   8.0  16.0   13.0
1      B          32             24           8.0   13.0   NaN   9.0   10.0
2      C          10             10           NaN    NaN  10.0   NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to do a groupby and unstack:

```py
(df
.groupby(['set_id', 'is_spare'])
.quantity
.sum()
.unstack('is_spare')
.rename(columns={False:'normal_pieces', True:'spare_pieces'})
.assign(num_pieces = lambda df: df.sum(axis = 'columns'))
.rename_axis(columns=None)
.reset_index()
)

  set_id  normal_pieces  spare_pieces  num_pieces
0      A           29.0           8.0        37.0
1      B           24.0           8.0        32.0
2      C           10.0           NaN        10.0
```

For the updated solution, you can use a groupby and unstack - I'll just jump straight to the `pivot_table`, which is a wrapper around groupby and pivot:

```py
temp = df.pivot_table(index='set_id', 
                      columns=['is_spare', 'color'], 
                      values='quantity', 
                      aggfunc='sum')
# get the sum of `red`, `blue`, ...
colors = temp.groupby(level='color', axis=1).sum(1)

#pandas MultiIndex works nicely here
# where we can select the top columns and sum
# in this case, `False`, and `True`
(temp.assign(num_pieces = temp.sum(1), 
             normal_pieces = temp[False].sum(1), 
             spare_pieces = temp[True].sum(1), 
             # assign is basically an expansion of a dictionary
             # and here we take advantage of that
             **colors)
     .drop(columns=[False, True])
     .reset_index()
     .rename_axis(columns=[None, None], index=None)
)
  set_id num_pieces normal_pieces spare_pieces black  grey   red white
                                                                      
0      A       37.0          29.0          8.0   0.0   8.0  16.0  13.0
1      B       32.0          24.0          8.0  13.0   0.0   9.0  10.0
2      C       10.0          10.0          0.0   0.0  10.0   0.0   0.0
```

Another option, that may be a bit faster (groupby is called only once), is to use get_dummies, before grouping:

```py
temp = df.set_index('set_id').loc[:, ['is_spare', 'color', 'quantity']]

# get_dummies returns 0 and 1, depending on if the value exists
# so if `blue` exists for a row, 1 is assigned, else 0
(pd.get_dummies(temp.drop(columns='quantity'), 
                columns = ['is_spare', 'color'], 
                prefix='', 
                prefix_sep='')
    # here we do a conditional replacement
    # similar to python's if-else statement
    # replacing the 1s with quantity
   .where(lambda df: df == 0, temp.quantity, axis = 0)
    # from here on it is grouping
    # with some renaming
   .groupby('set_id')
   .sum()
   .assign(num_pieces = lambda df: df[['False', 'True']].sum(1))
   .rename(columns={'False':'normal_pieces', 'True':'spare_pieces'})
)

        normal_pieces  spare_pieces  black  grey  red  white  num_pieces
set_id                                                                  
A                  29             8      0     8   16     13          37
B                  24             8     13     0    9     10          32
C                  10             0      0    10    0      0          10
```

Comment: I like Corralien's trick, but I would rather accept this answer because it looks more scalable to me for a non-boolean column (i.e., a 4th column with 'color' of pieces, either red/blue/black/white).  Could you extend your answer to `groupby(['set_id','is_spare','color'])` and unstacking both `is_spare` and `color` in one line ... so the resulting output dataframe has 4 new columns `red, blue, black, white` for accounting also the sum of pieces of each color?

Comment: Kindly update your question to include these new details

Comment: Done (I also modified the title accordingly). BTW, any idea about performance of `groupby/sum/unstack`, compared to my original `groupby/agg(sum)/merge` strategy, when the original dataframe is much longer (i.e. 100K to 1M rows)?

Comment: Your merge requires building multiple frames, compared to the groupby unstack, which works on a single dataframe. Since less dataframe d are involved, the groupby instack should be faster. Tests are the true way to verify tho

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. As a pandas beginner, it will be hard for me to understand what's happening there. Would you mind to help a bit more commenting (#) your different codes? Re-thanks

Comment: @abu, added some comments to the code. Let me know if you need more explanation

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one line. The trick is to create a temporary column where quantity is negative for `spare_pieces` and positive for `normal_pieces`:

```
out = df.assign(qty=df['is_spare'].replace({True: -1, False: 1}) * df['quantity']) \
        .groupby('set_id')['qty'] \
        .agg(num_pieces=lambda x: sum(abs(x)), 
             normal_pieces=lambda x: sum(x[x > 0]),
             sparse_pieces=lambda x: abs(sum(x[x < 0]))) \
        .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  set_id  num_pieces  normal_pieces  sparse_pieces
0      A          37             29              8
1      B          32             24              8
2      C          10             10              0

>>> df['is_spare'].replace({True: -1, False: 1}) * df['quantity'])
0     1  # normal_pieces
1     1
2     9
3     1
4     7
5    -4  # spare_pieces
6     7
7     1
8     9
9    -4
10   -8
11    8
12    9
13    4
14    6
dtype: int64
```